# How to alert all p using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I learn on how to alert all html code from webpage using this code:

```
var markup = document.document.innerHTML; 
alert(markup);
```

I want to alert only all `<p>`

I tried this code

```
var markup = document.getElementsByTag('p').innerHTML;
alert(markup);`
```

But it's not working

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName()`. And that produces a Nodelist you have to loop. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("p")` returns a HTMLCollection which you can convert to an array using the spread operator. Then you need to get the `innerHTML` for each element of the array. Finally you can join those `innerHTML` together to output them:

```js
var pElements = [ ... document.getElementsByTagName("p") ];
var pMarkup   = pElements.map( element => element.innerHTML );
alert( pMarkup.join( "\n" ) );
```

```html
<p>abc<strong>def</strong></p>
<table><tr><td>Don't show this</td></tr></table>
<p>ghi<em>jkl</em></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after `HTMLElement.outerHTML`

```js
// All p's
const pTags = document.querySelectorAll('p');

const output = [...pTags].map(p => p.outerHTML).join("");

console.log(output);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="red">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at fermentum turpis. Maecenas congue accumsan enim, et dictum turpis malesuada et.
</p>
<p>
  Mauris vitae pretium tortor. Aenean nulla ante, scelerisque in erat ac, tincidunt porttitor dolor. Sed blandit sed mi at vulputate.
</p>
<p id="three">
  Curabitur lobortis at augue at hendrerit. Mauris id ligula cursus ligula dictum viverra.
</p>
<p>
  Sed suscipit varius orci. Duis sit amet fermentum eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin commodo turpis in neque aliquam, et laoreet odio consequat.
</p>
<p data-number="5">
  Nam dolor neque, lacinia sed viverra et, cursus ac ipsum. Cras gravida quam enim, sit amet tristique urna faucibus non.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus cursus, justo a volutpat pulvinar, ligula metus mollis turpis, in tincidunt ante nisl non nunc.
</p>
```